# Adding 64 bit fix to Cocos2d makes all CCActions act crazy

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Some background:
I was forced to add a 64 bit fix to a game built using Cocos2d v2 before publishing the game and I did that using different little hacks from a tutorial, which solved the problem but also led to some nasty sprite flickering on the 64 bit devices.

To solve the graphics issues, I´ve now decided to add the Cocos2d v2.2 fix: I simply replaced the libs/cocos2d folder for the project. This removed the flickering bug, but also made all my CCActions act super weird:

- They move slower than before (still the same code)
- They go too far in certain directions
- CCSequence does not run all the actions for about 80% of the time -

I can´t find the cause of this. Does the 64x runtime change something that can cause this? (considering the floating points changes.)

Comment: hmmm ... i have done the same for one of my published apps and so far have no performance issue whatsoever !  are you observing these anomalies in a simulator or in devices ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg both device and simulator